# Alternatives to writing joins with foreign keys in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel-eloquent and want to return a collection that joins several tables. For now, I do this using the query builder join method, but I would like to stay within eloquent. I mean, I already defined all my relationships, why should I write joins with foreign keys all the time?

For example, if I have defined my models like this:

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
    }
}

<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

and want to return all the comments with the user names, for now I would write  this:

```php
DB::table('users')->select('users.name', 'comments.body')
->join('comments', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')
->get();
```

I have tried writing

```php
$users = new 'App\User';
$users->with('comments')
->select('name', 'comments.body');
```

but it didn't work. Do I need to define a new collection? I will end up with many, many collections if I do that...

Comment: How exactly did the ->with('comments') not work? Is there a reason behind you creating a new User in the second example while you get a user in the first one? If you're creating a new user. it won't have any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = null; 
$users = new 'App\User';
$records = $users->with('comments')->get(); 

if ($records->isNotEmpty()){
  $result = $records->map(function($val,$key){
    return ["name"=>$val->name, "comments" => $val->comments()->get(['body']);
  })->values()->all(); 
}

dd($result);
```

I have not tested the codes yet. Please check and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

you should try the following code:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user')->get();
dd($comments);
```

It's always the table that has many values join the table with single value in Eloquent model